# Can you build a suit that acts against gravity?

Tags: physics

For instance, could a person build a suit that went against gravity enough that you could go through a black hole and survive?

Comment: Welcome to the site Isicial.  Can you provide some context around your question?  What are you trying to accomplish, what resources are available in the world?

Comment: While this makes no sense, I think it's a great cheesy sci-fi premise. Just do it with a bit of technobabble

Comment: I can think of a couple of really hyper-advanced pieces of super sci-fi technology that _might_ do what you're asking **but** that's based on a guess as to what you actually want, because right now this question doesn't have a clear goal.

Comment: It is not so much the force of gravity that is the problem, but the gravitational gradients that will cause tidal forces and tear you apart. A large enough black hole has a very shallow well at the event horizon. Entire planets could exist inside. Eventually though as you approach the singularity at the center, the gradient approaches infinity and you will get torn up. A big question is what do you mean by "go through" They are not really holes in the sense that scifi likes to depict them. Most literature tends to agree that there is no where to go on the other side.

Comment: "Antigravity" isn't a thing of science yet, so we have to wait until this question can be answered. As far as "going through" a black hole, modern science tells us that even a particle with no mass can't do that. However, there are other ideas (mostly in sci-fi) that black holes are actually portals. According to them, we may not even need an antigravity suit to travel through a black hole.

Answer (score 12):

To the best of our knowledge, no. There are 2 BIG problems to consider. The first is how to nullify gravity. We have no way to do this at present. You can act against it - you can jump, for example - but that does not eliminate the gravity acting on you, it just counteracts it. You can act against any force of gravity, but that won't stop it from tearing you apart.

The second is the nature of black holes. We still know next to nothing about them. You mention going "through" them, but we don't even know if there's something on the other side to go "through" to. Ideas about what happen to you past the event horizon are just speculation.

Hand-wavium is pretty much all that can get you where you're trying to go. You can research theoretical physics to make your explanation sound more plausible, but ultimately, you're going to be making stuff up.

Comment: *We still know next to nothing about them*  You may know next to nothing about black holes, but don't drag the rest of us down with you. :-)  They're a subject of intense study by physicists and we've a lot of info on this subject.

Comment: We do collect tons of data, and there are a lot of theories, but the last time I did any research on it, it was still like looking at a cat across the street saying, "We've discovered that it's furry and has a tail!" without knowing anything about what it actually is beyond theories that it's probably warm blooded and most likely has teeth in its mouth. Are we past that point now? If so, I'd love to hear about it. (And I don't doubt that you and others know FAR more about them than me. It may be "just" theorizing, but that doesn't make it simple or obvious. It's impressive beyond belief)

Comment: *without knowing anything about what it actually is beyond theories* Beyond the theories is kinda meaningless in Physics.  You build theories that match what you see (measure) and that's all there is.

Comment: Fair point. :) And especially in the case of black holes, direct testing would be pretty fatal/impossible.